# How do I trigger script authorization when file is opened/created?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet in which users enter inputs that are then copied into a slides template on the click of a custom menu button. The way workflow is currently set up, users make a copy of the "master" sheet every time they wish to use the tool. As a result, every time a user clicks the custom menu item that triggers the script to copy data into the slides template, they have to authorize the script first, and then click the button again to actually have the script run (see screenshots below).

Does anybody know if there is a way to set things up such that the user is prompted to authorize the script associated with the sheet immediately upon opening the sheet? That way when they click the custom menu button the script will just run without further authentication prompt.

I have tried calling the `getOAuthToken()` method from within the `onOpen()` trigger to see if that would force users to authenticate upon opening, but that didn't work.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Exceptions Slides');
  menu.addItem('Generate Slides', 'createNewGoogleSlides');
  menu.addToUi();
  var authToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

[image: Authorization Required]

[image: Authorization]

Comment: Authorize the file from the script editor after opening and then next time  you won't have to.

Comment: @Cooper every time the file is used it, the user makes a copy of the "master" sheet, so it needs to be re-authorized with each use. I am trying to figure out how to prompt the user for authorization immediately after they make their copy.

Comment: I don't think you can and it's not a big deal.